# Отключается openvpn при подключении 2 человек

Tags: хостинг, vps, vpn, openvpn

Сделал vpn сервер на vps используя openvpn. При подключении второго клиента к vpn, у первого клиента пропадает сигнал.
Конфиги генерировал для каждого отдельные.
Год назад как-то смог эту проблему пофиксить, а сейчас уже не помню что делал.
Кто сталкивался и шарит?